# C++ Anonymous Unions - Instantiating a const array in constructor

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, instantiation

Ive been struggling with this problem from an assignment for while, wondered  if anyone would be kind enough to help out?

I'm trying to learn about anonymous unions in C++ and using them for a quaternion.

I'm having trouble figuring out the syntax to declare the const vars of an array in a constructor.

Here the anon struct

```
union {
        static const float* arr = new float[4];
        struct {
            const float _x;
            const float _y;
            const float _z;
            const float _w;
        };
    };
```

I've tried quite a few combinations now with no luck.

```
Quaternion::Quaternion(const float x1, const float y1, const float z1, const float w1) :
        ?, ?, ?, ? {}
```

Thanks

Comment: `arr` should be an array, not a pointer. Even then, switching between the two union members (e.g. writing to the array and reading from _x) is undefined behavior although it will work on many compilers.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. To make arr an array - does that mean declaring it on the stack. ie. float arr[4].

Comment: Yes, that's how you'd declare it (though it doesn't mean on the stack - it's a member and has the same storage as the union).

Comment: So would depend how i instantiated the quaternion class? A requirement is that the quaternion is instantiated on the stack, with the private floats on the heap. I'm happy to just use an array outside of an anonymous union, was just curious i guess.